# Simplifying indexed exponents with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to use SymPy to work with some summations and products but I cannot get SymPy to simplify the expressions involving indexed symbols.

Here is a simple example:

```
A = symbols('A', real=True)
A_i = Indexed(A, i)

expr_1 = exp(-1/A)**A
expr_2 = exp(-1/A_i)**A_i
```

Then, running `powsimp(expr_1)` returns e^-1 as expected but `powsimp(expr_2)` just returns the original unsimplified expression.

What is the right way to work with indexed variables when trying to simplify them?

Note: Bringing in an actual summation since that is what I am trying to do, running `powsimp(summation(expr_1, (i, 1, I)))` returns I/e as expected but `powsimp(summation(expr_2, (i, 1, I)))` still returns the unsimplified expression.

Comment: The change happens before powersimp: if `r` is real then `exp(-1/r)**r` -> `exp(-1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `exp(-1/A)**A` is equal to `exp(-1)` if A is real, but not in general. For example,

```
a = symbols('a')
expr = (exp(-1/a)**a).subs(a, I/(2*pi))    # returns 1
```

(here `I` is a built-in SymPy constant `I`, the imaginary unit).

So the assumption of being real is necessary for simplification. And at present (v1.3) SymPy [does not support assumptions on indexed symbols](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13992). Although `powsimp` has a flag `force=True` meant to force simplification by ignoring assumptions, this does not have an effect on `exp(-1/a)**a`.

As a workaround, I offer a function `powsimp_indexed` which takes an expression and optional parameters: `force` as above, and `indexed_assumptions`. All indexed symbols in the expression are replaced by "dummies" with `indexed_assumptions`, simplification is made, and then the substitution is undone.

Examples:

```
>>> powsimp_indexed(expr_2)
exp(-1/A[i])**A[i]
>>> powsimp_indexed(expr_2, real=True)
exp(-1)
>>> powsimp_indexed(Sum(expr_2, (i, 1, M)), real=True).doit()
exp(-1)*M
```

In the latter, simplification needs to happen before summation: hence, the `Sum` is an inert (non-evaluated) sum, it first gets simplified, and then `doit()` performs summation.

```
def powsimp_indexed(expr, force=False, **indexed_assumptions):
    indexed_syms = {t for t in expr_2.free_symbols if isinstance(t, Indexed)}
    subs = {}
    inverse_subs = {}
    for s in indexed_syms:
        d = Dummy('xi', **indexed_assumptions)
        subs[s] = d
        inverse_subs[d] = s
    return powsimp(expr.xreplace(subs), force=force).xreplace(inverse_subs)
```